# Conditions within ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, conditional-statements, preconditions

I am new to R and I (probably) have a simple question, but I am unable to get my head around it. Even though I have been trying it in multiple ways:

I want to make a plot from a subgroup of a certain classification (aneurysm type) as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= MSS, y= Aneurysm_Volume)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = df$TF1_months, y = df$AV1[df$xaneurysm_type == 1])) +
  geom_point(aes(x = df$TF2_months, y = df$AV2[df$xaneurysm_type == 1])) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = df$TF3_months, y = df$AV3[df$xaneurysm_type == 1])) +
  geom_point(aes(x = df$TF4_months, y = df$AV4[df$xaneurysm_type == 1])) +
  geom_point(aes(x = df$TF5_months, y = df$AV5[df$xaneurysm_type == 1])) +
  xlim(0, NA) + ylim(0, NA)
```

However, the following error applies.
*Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (154): y*

I tried to make a seperate variably for Y as follows:

```
if(df$xaneurysm_type == 1) {
   (df$juxtavolume1 = df$AV1)
} else {
  (df$juxtavolume1 = NA)
}
```

However, the following warning applies:

*Warning message:
In if (df$xaneurysm_type == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

I have also tried to make the conditional variable the following way:

```
df$juxtavolume1 <- as.integer(NA)
df[which(df$xaneurysm_type == 1),]$juxtavolume1 <- as.integer(df$AV1)
```

But then the following error applies:
*Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, juxtavolume1, value = c(NA_integer_,  : 
  replacement has 154 rows, data has 97*

Does anybody understand where I am going wrong? Your help is much appreciated!

Warm regards

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You are probably going to want to reshape your data rather than adding a bunch of layers.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're using multiple different x variables in your plot. Try plotting only a few at a time, or convert your data to long data, i.e. tidy data, instead of the wide format that you have.

Comment: Reshape first. Never use `$` inside `aes`. You want to use `ifelse()` instead of `if () else`.